# Find datarows with the same id in C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access

It is my first time working with Datarows or tabular data. Considering I have a simple table with two columns, one contains the ID and the other contains a name string. What I need to do is find two Datarows with the same ID, and pass these two rows to another function, lets call it `HandleTheDuplicates`.

At the moment I am trying store the previous ID in another variable and check if this matches to the current ID and then add it to a list of type DataRow.

```
List<DataRow> RowList = new List<DataRow>();
int previous = 0 ;
foreach (DataRow rowToMatch in importSetOfTables.Tables["MyTable"].Rows)
{
     int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(rowToMatch["ID"]);                               
     if (previous == rowID)
     {
          RowList.Add(rowToMatch);
     }
     else
     {
          RowList.Clear();
     }
     previous = rowID;

     if(RowList.Count > 1) //in case of a match
     {
          HandleTheDuplicates(RowList);
     }
}
```

I don't know if this is the right way of doing something like this or if there could be something more simpler.

Comment: This could work but only if your table is sorted by ID

Comment: Why "else RowList.Clear();"?  Wouldn't you want to leave the matching rows in there?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! 
Steve: In case the table is not sorted, then what can I do?
Jason: Sorry I should have explained better, I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is a good option here:

```
List<DataRow> RowList = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow row in importSetOfTables.Tables["MyTable"].Rows)
{
    // Use LINQ to get a list of rows matching on ID
    List<DataRow> matches = (from t in importSetOfTables.Tables["MyTable"].Rows
                             where row.ID == t.ID
                             select a).ToList();
    // Insert matching rows into your collection
    if (matches.Count() > 0 )
         if (!(RowList.Contains(matches[0]))
             RowList.AddRange(matches);
}
```

If you want to remove them from the original collection, another foreach loop might work: (Generally don't want to remove items from a collection you are iterating over)

```
foreach(DataRow row in RowList)
{
    if (importSetOfTables.Tables["MyTable"].Rows.Contains(row))
        importSetOfTables.Tables["MyTable"].Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Comment: It looks like every row will match itself if you use that first code block.  Also, each match of two different rows will show up twice:  once when `row` is the first matching row, and once when `row` is the other match.  Neither of these is necessarily wrong; just something to be aware of.

Comment: Good find! As far as your first point though, I don't see it as a problem, It will return all the rows that match it, including itself, isn't that the spec in the question? You're right that you wouldn't want copies of the match though, that can be fixed with another condition in the if, which i will edit in now. Thanks for the catch! @jason44107

Answer (score 1):

Your code could work if you have the DataTable sorted by ID. To be sure then  set the [`DataTable.DefaultView.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the ID field and then create your loop using the DataTable.DefaultView

```
List<DataRow> RowList = new List<DataRow>();
int previous = 0 ;
importSetOfTables.Tables["MyTable"].DefaultView.Sort = "ID";
foreach (DataRowView rw in importSetOfTables.Tables["MyTable"].DefaultView)
{
     int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(rw["ID"]);
     if (previous == rowID)
          RowList.Add(rw.Row);
     else
     {
          // Call the function that handles the duplicates
          if(RowList.Count > 1) 
             HandleTheDuplicates(RowList);
          RowList.Clear();
     }
     previous = rowID;
}
```